# Entity Framework Core Insert into multiple tables in one round trip

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-core

I have never tried to insert data into multiple tables before using EF Core.

Say I have this method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _ordersService.Insert(Order);    
    _clientService.Insert(Client);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

as far as i know SaveChanges makes a round trip per insert. Should i use a stored procedure instead or is there a way to handle this?

I have used EF.Extenstions to insert bulk data but in this case tables are different so i would like to know what is the most performant approach in this situation while using EF Core.

**EDIT**

Forgot to add there is a relation between Clients and Orders,

1 Client > Many Orders

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, SP that inserts Order and Clent at once would basically always  be more performant than what EF does (DB roundtrips, internal housekeeping and entities fixup...), but do you really need to optimize to such an [extent](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)? Or do you have a specific bulk insert scenario for two tables (`I have used EF.Extenstions to insert bulk data...`)?

Comment: I have posted more details. SP is only an alternative to EF if it requires more than one round trip to do what i need to do. The Insert bulk was only in a situation of ' 
`Insert into myTable VALUES (x),(y),(z)`

Comment: It will probably do it in this case (foreign key), but you can easily check it by adding some logging - https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/logging-in-entityframework-core.aspx.